# All routes except "/" return 404 from Nginx running Flask WSGI

Tags: nginx, flask

I have a [flaskapp, deployed using nginx as proxy server and gunicorn](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-gunicorn-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-18-04).
I have several routes defined in the Flask python script, except they aren't accessible.

When using development server, however, they work just fine.

All routes except the base url ("/") return 404 nginx page, so I'm assuming there's something with nginx, but I found nothing that could help me with it.

How to configure nginx to accept these routes and use the one defined in flaskApp?

Answer (score 1):

That's because you did not define all the routes in your nginx configuration, you should have something like the example below, except that you should change `server_name` and `ports`.

Note : I was using this snippet to connect nginx to other containers so think about changing http://client:80; to your localhost or application name, also do the same for all the routes.

The main idea is to define all routes.

```
http {

         server {
             
            listen 80;
            server_name localhost 127.0.0.1;

            location / {
                proxy_pass          http://client:80;
                proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
            }

            location /api/ {
                    # why should i add / at the end 5000/ to make it work 
                proxy_pass          http://api:5000/;
                proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
            }
            
            location /api/client {
                proxy_pass          http://api:5000/client;
                proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
            }
}
```